# Firefox sometimes adds space when I select a word

Tags: firefox, passwords, clipboard

I have this text in my browser window:

```
Your userid is XXX
Your temporary password is JBAQJiK9 

Please visit `<URL>` and update your password and profile
```

If I double click on any word **except the password** + <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, I end up with the word in the clipboard. If I double click the password, I end up with `JBAQJiK9<space>` in the clipboard, that is an additional space character is appended to the password. This causes me some problems when I copy&paste the password into the login form since I can't see what's happening. Damn security by obscurity. :-(

In the source, I can see this:

```
Your userid is XXX<br />
Your temporary password is JBAQJiK9 <br />
```

So there is a space but I can't see it and I can't select it while I can select the space between "password" and "is", for example.

Is this a bug in Firefox 4 or is it a security feature?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=524975